# Monitor/Prevent copying files from a computer

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, monitoring

I am giving remote desktop access to my computer to someone to get some work done. I want them NOT to copy any files out of my computer. Is there any software to monitor or prevent copying?

Comment: Block their access to the computer with a firewall. Or don't grant them log on rights.

Comment: If they can read the file, they can copy the file.

Answer (score 1):

If they are skilled and want your data there is not much you can do since you are allowing them a remote session on your PC, there is this software you can use for most people it will work. Remember this does not block all ways data can be moved from your PC to another location on the internet.

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-cut-paste-copy-delete-re-naming-of-files-folders

Other than that move your data you do not want copied off of that PC to a external hard drive, and be sure it is disconnected from the PC when they remote in.

If you do not trust them, do not allow them to remote in to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

The account that you're setting up on your machine doesn't have to be an admin. Create the account that you want and give specific folder permissions to that user account.

Assuming windows 7:

1. Create an account in "User Accounts". I'll call mine RDP.
2. Make your way to System Properties (start > type "select users who can use remote desktop")
3. Select "Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication"
4. Click "Select Users"
5. Click "Add" > Add the user account you created
6. Ok a bunch of times till you're back at your desktop
7. On whatever folders you don't want the account to access on your HD, right click > properties > security tab
8. Click Edit
9. Click Add > type the user's name, click Ok
10. Check "Full Control - Deny" (It will check deny for all options beneath it)
11. Fin.